# Convert MemoryStream to FileStream with C#?

Tags: c#, filestream, memorystream

I am working on a project that receives a FileStream and it should receive it with a method that returns a MemoryStream.

**How can I convert the MemoryStream to FileStream?** I can't touch those codes and there lies the entire problem.

Comment: Could you show an example of the signature of the method that you need to invoke and what you have as input. Your question is not clear why you need such conversion.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov. Your deleted answer looks valid. why did you delete it?

Comment: Because I need to first understand what the OP is asking. His question doesn't make any sense and I prefer to have more information before posting a real answer.

Comment: I think the OP has an API like `void DoSomething(FileStream stream)` which he cannot change. He wants to use it with a `MemoryStream`, presumably without writing the data to a file first.

Comment: If this is the case then he cannot achieve that. A FileStream is a pointer to a file. You cannot possibly convert a MemoryStream that you have created in memory to a FileStream. This doesn't make any sense. He will have to flush the contents of this MemoryStream (that he presumably has) to a temporary file and then pass a FileStream to this file to his presumable API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a Stream to a FileStream in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769067/convert-a-stream-to-a-filestream-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Any particular reason you're insisting on a `FileStream`?  Would it not be possible to have the function that wants a `FileStream`, take a `Stream` instead?  If all it wants is a stream of bytes, it shouldn't be caring where those bytes come from.  And if it *needs* those bytes to come from a file, a `MemoryStream` simply won't cut it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a method that returns a MemoryStream, and you need to pass that stream to a method that takes a FileStream.  I've seen several instances where colleagues of mine have written methods with a FileStream parameter when the parameter type could have been Stream.  This is an excellent example of why it's better to use the less-derived type for the parameter.

The only solution I can think of is to write the memory stream to a temporary file: create a file stream for the temporary file, copy the memory stream to the file stream, and then either set the position to zero or close the stream and open a new stream on the same file, to pass to the method.

If I have misunderstood your question, please clarify.