# How to upload file to Azure DataLake through API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, file-upload, azure-data-lake, iformfile

Net core application. I am trying to upload file to data lake through API. I have below controller method which accepts file.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile files)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Uploads", files.FileName);
            var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
            string containerName = "raw";
            DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeServiceClient = _dataLakeRepository.GetDataLakeServiceClient("test");
            DataLakeFileSystemClient dataLakeFileSystemClient = _dataLakeRepository.GetFileSystem(dataLakeServiceClient, containerName);
            await _dataLakeRepository.UploadFile(dataLakeFileSystemClient, "directory2", "text1.txt", stream);
            return Ok();
        }
```

I have below DataLake method which will upload file to data lake.

```
 public async Task UploadFile(DataLakeFileSystemClient fileSystemClient, string directoryName, string fileName, Stream content)
        {
            DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient = fileSystemClient.GetDirectoryClient(directoryName);

            DataLakeFileClient fileClient = await directoryClient.CreateFileAsync(fileName);

            long fileSize = content.Length;

            await fileClient.AppendAsync(content, offset: 0);

            await fileClient.FlushAsync(position: fileSize);
        }
```

Below method to get file system client

```
public DataLakeFileSystemClient GetFileSystem(DataLakeServiceClient serviceClient, string FileSystemName)
        {
            return serviceClient.GetFileSystemClient(FileSystemName);
        }
```

I tried to upload file and In below line

> await fileClient.AppendAsync(content, offset: 0);

I got below error

```
Azure.RequestFailedException: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
Status: 400 (The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.)
ErrorCode: InvalidHeaderValue
```

Also when I debug I see content.Length is also zero. I think I am missing something in stream because I am having some issue with stream. I am not able to figure out the issue. Can someone help me to fix this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After read official doc, we can find the sample code use `FileStream`.

So you should convert `Stream` to `FileStream` .

[image]

Comment: Hi Jsaon, Thanks I am following the same but how we can convert to filestream?

Comment: @MrPerfect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640768/casting-stream-to-filestream

Comment: Yeah actually tried this but no luck and same error

Comment: @MrPerfect Let me try it.

Comment: @MrPerfect First, can you show us how did you create `DataLakeFileSystemClient` ?

Comment: Hi Json, I have added method in the question

Comment: @MrPerfect https://i.imgur.com/Y692k3s.png I mean which way you use to create  DataLakeServiceClient ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235877/discussion-between-mr-perfect-and-jason-pan).